# jQuery Function Problem (Parent/Child)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I have a small problem with a jQuery script I wrote.

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Link1"><b>Text1</b></a></li>
    <li><a href="Link2"><b>Text2</b></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then, I have a click function binded to those li/a tabs that sets the value of the current page to href:

```
var currentpage = $(this).attr('href');
```

And, finally, an update function that is fired when it's needed that do many thing, but also changes the style of the currently selected li/a tab:

```
$('#navigation a').each(function()
{
  var tab = $(this);
  tab.parent().toggleClass('current', (tab.attr('href') == currentpage));
});
```

Everything works fine, but today I was trying to rewrite the last function on one line only -without calling each()- and I can't get it to work.
I've tried many solutions like:

```
$('#navigation a').parent().toggleClass('current', ($(this).children(':first').attr('href') === currentpage));

$('#navigation a').parent().toggleClass('current', ($(':only-child', $(this)).attr('href') == currentpage));
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rewrite it as you'd like to.

The original code has to use ".each()" because it needs access to each individual `<a>` element in order to do its thing.  In your rewrite, you're imagining that you can get `this` set to each element being processed, but that's just not how `this` works in JavaScript. In your attempted rewrite, the value of `this` in those parameters to "toggleClass()" will be `this` as it stands *outside* that entire jQuery function call chain. It'll have absolutely nothing to do with the `<a>` elements being processed by the call to "toggleClass()".

Answer (score 0):

when your function is triggers i.e. on clicking the in that function you can get the reference to the clicked element,  tag by using $(this). Then your code should be

```
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current', ($(this).children(':first').attr('href') === currentpage));
```